# How to stop Flash Builder from caching Compiler config files specified by -load-config

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, caching, flash-builder, config

Every time I try to change a compiler constant, it seems I HAVE to:

- Do a *Project -> Clean*.
- Close *Flash Builder*.
- Wait for it to fully close (does it's Workspace save thing...)
- Re-Launch *Flash Builder* (and again, wait for it to finish loading...)
- Re-Build All (*got 3 projects dependent of eachother*).
- Test *Run/Debug* it (or Export a Release version).

This is extremely annoying and time-consuming. Is there a setting somewhere I can set so that Flash Builder ALWAYS reads the latest changes in the custom Compiler config.xml file I've made?

It basically contains something like this:
[image]

Changes to something as simple as the Version # becomes a long process.

Any workarounds?

Comment: Did you try right click the source folder -> refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Flash Builder user, so take this with a pinch of salt. Some possible workarounds:

**Define your constants in the project itself**

Your problem seems to be that Flash Builder isn't picking up changes in an external file - from some quick searching on google, it seems to be a pretty common problem with no particular solution other than what you're doing (or going back to 4.6).

To declare your consts in the project itself, go to *Project Settings > ActionScript Compiler* and under *Additional Compiler Arguments* add your constants like so:

```
-define+=COMPILE::LANG_EN,true
-define+=COMPILE::LANG_FR,false
...
```

Each one needs to be on a separate line, and you *might* need to replace `COMPILE` with `CONFIG` (the default)

**Build your project using ANT**

It can be a bit of a pain to set up, but once it's done, you should be fine. You should be able to declare them like so:

```
<mxmlc ... > 
    <define name="CONFIG::LANG_EN" value="true"/> 
    <define name="CONFIG::LANG_FR" value="false"/> 
</mxmlc>
```

Taken from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html

**Define your constants in code**

It's possible to define compile constants directly in code, though it only works for the block of code it's declared in (e.g. class level). Depending on what you need it for (i.e. if you're setting up different values vs actually removing code), this could do what you need (e.g. set it up on a constants class, to set the value of different constants depending on the compile const. Then use those constants throughout your code)

```
package
{
    config namespace COMPILE;
    COMPILE const LANG_EN = true;
    COMPILE const LANG_FR = !COMPILE::LANG_EN;

    public class MyClass
    {
        public function MyClass()
        {
            this.sayHello();
        }

        COMPILE::LANG_EN
        public function sayHello():void
        {
            trace("hello");
        }

        COMPILE::LANG_FR
        public function sayHello():void
        {
            trace("bonjour");
        }

        public function foo():void
        {
            COMPILE::LANG_EN { trace( "foo" ); }
            COMPILE::LANG_FR { trace( "bar" ); }
        }

    }
}
```

**Change IDE**

FlashDevelop can be your friend here. In the office, I work on FlashDevelop, and some of the other devs work using FlashBuilder. Each has their own strong points.

We use compiler constants defined using the first method for situations where blocks of code need to be removed (i.e. supporting mobile and web builds), and we use an embedded XML for other "constants" depending on the build; version, server ip, api keys, etc. Which XML gets embedded in the case of the latter depends on a single compiler const.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I would definitely prefer to use FlashDevelop at work, but unfortunately the way we organize our projects, we usually create 3 Flash Projects for every single game "project" (1 Title project, 1 InGame, and 1 Loader [embeds the previous two]), and "Flash Builder" seems to be a better IDE to handle this kind of setup (although I disagree with this code organization greatly, but can't win the debate with my coworkers).

Comment: I wonder if your **constants in code** example actually omits the bytecodes of the blocks with a 'false' result, or includes it but never gets executed anyways?
It might be worth doing a quick analysis with *JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler* or something similar.

Comment: yeah, setting up the project initially so it can be used in FlashDevelop and Flash Builder is a bit of a pain, but so far, it's working fine. As for the constants in code, from what I can tell, the block is removed (otherwise you'd have a compile error for a function with the same name - `sayHello()`). That said, I've not verified it ;)

Comment: ah yes, that would make sense!